# How to solve these two social wordpress plugins conflict issue?

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I download these two plugin wp-social-invitations and wp social login. Unfortunately they have a conflict that I cannot activate them both at the same time. I create two different Facebook AppId, and insert into each plugin. When I try to use the wp social login with Facebook login, it gave me the message 
 Fatal error: Class 'Hybrid_Logger' not found in /home2/name/public_html/mysite/wp-content/plugins/wp-social-invitations/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php on line 238

I click the Login With Facebook( the wp social login plugin), the error message give me an error that relate to wp-social-invitations, I know it must be conflict. I really want to keep both of them, how can I fix this issue.Appreciate!

Comment: Can you provide some code snippets and which line is causing this error? Check to make sure the class Hybrid_Logger is defined before instantiating it.

Comment: This isn't really programming. This is how to run a WP site... Try superuser, maybe.